# Как в git branch изменить формат вывода даты?

Tags: git, git-branch

Каким образом в git branch изменить формат вывода даты?

```
git branch --format="[%(color:yellow)%(committerdate:short)%(color:reset)] - %(color:bold magenta)%(subject)%(color:reset)"
```

выводит в формате `%Y-%m-%d`, хотелось бы `%d.%m.%Y`

Comment: `%(committerdate:format:%d.%m.%Y)`

Comment: @mymedia, огромное спасибо! Второй день копаю доки, так и не нашёл)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь такой подстановкой: `%(committerdate:format:%d.%m.%Y)`

```
git branch --format="[%(color:yellow)%(committerdate:format:%d.%m.%Y)%(color:reset)] - %(color:bold magenta)%(subject)%(color:reset)"
```

---

Документация в этом случае и в самом деле запутанная. До вашего вопроса я ничего не знал про параметр `--format` команды branch и искал информацию следующим образом. Вначале открыл страницу [**git-branch**(1)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/git-branch.1.html) и выполнил поиск подстроки "--format". Описание опции ссылается на [**git-for-each-ref**(1)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/git-for-each-ref.1.html), я открыл эту страницу и повторил поиск. Там рассказывается про форму записи с процентами со скобками `%(fieldname)`, а разделе FIELD NAMES более подробно говорится о форматировании полей. В частности, выполнив поиск по подстроке "committerdate", я увидел отсылку к опции `--date` из [**git-rev-list**(1)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/git-rev-list.1.html), а там расписано, что можно писать после первого двоеточия внутри круглых скобок. В том числе, перечисляется использованный вами формат `short`. В абзаце про `format:...` и `format-local:...` есть упоминание [**strftime**(3)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man3/strftime.3.html), где описаны возможные процентные спецификаторы для форматирования дат.